# How to display : none button when show "Please wait redirect page......"

Tags: php, forms, button

How to display : none button when show "Please wait redirect page......"

When i click "OK" button , it's will show text "Please wait redirect page......" AND loading bar image

and i want to `display : none;`button , How can i do ?

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
?>
            <div style=" text-align: center;  padding: 300px; font-family: trebuchet ms; ">
                Please wait redirect page......<br>
            <img src="http://microsite.nintendo-europe.com/658363683991c1bc33a9b502274dd651/en_ZA/images/loadingBar.gif" border="0">                     
<?PHP
        }
?>
        <form name ="news_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution:

```
<form name ="news_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" 
       <? if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { echo "'style=display:none'"; } ?>  
   />

</form>
```

Comment: I tried this and it works. @user3190706 you just need to add your extra stuff in there.

Comment: It's WORK ^^

`<? if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { echo "'style=display:none'"; } ?>`

thank you